# What is causing node to slow down despite velocity remaining constant?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a SCNSphere that is climbing a 45 degree hill.

The node maintains a consistent speed until the same point at every level, at which point it unexpectedly drops in speed, here is a 10 second clip of the issue.

The drop in speed occurs at 8 seconds in [this clip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qkQR4VqDR5Zb9CbPla4BHe5en76g4K3X).

When the node reaches a z position of -240, it seems as though the entire game speed is cut in half.

I have tested this in the following ways always without success.

- Tried testing without gravity.
- Tried testing without colliding with the hill.
- Tried testing without damping or friction.
- Tried printing the nodes velocity to notice any changes, although the velocity remains at -5.0 on the z axis for the duration of the
  level despite the significant drop in speed.
- Tried printing the physicsWorld speed to notice any changes, although the speed remains at 1.0 for the duration of the
  level despite the significant drop in speed.
- Checked for a drop in frame rate although it maintains a frame rate of 60 fps, making only 14 draw calls in total with a poly count under 15k.

The sphere's velocity is updated at every frame in the renderer using the following function.

```
func updatePositions() {

        if let playerPhysicsBod = playerNode.physicsBody {
            playerPhysicsBod.velocity.x = (lastXPosition - playerNode.position.x) * 8
            playerPhysicsBod.velocity.z = -5
            print("player velocity is \(playerNode.physicsBody!.velocity)")
        }
    }

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        updatePositions()
        updateSegments()
    }
```

This project is a fresh one, and so there aren't many lines, I will include the entire code base below.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {


    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/gameScene.scn")!
    let jump = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/jump.scn")!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "jump", recursively: true)!
    let box = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/box.scn")!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "box", recursively: true)!
    var playerNode = SCNNode()
    var cameraNode = SCNNode()
    var lastXPosition = Float()
    var floorSegments = [SCNNode]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
//        scnView.isJitteringEnabled = true
        scnView.scene = scene
        scnView.delegate = self
        scnView.showsStatistics = true

        setupCamera()
        setupPlayer()
        setupSegments()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let tLocationX = touches.first?.location(in: self.view).x else { return }
        let ratio = tLocationX / self.view.frame.maxX
        lastXPosition = Float((5 * ratio) - 2.5)

    }

    func setupCamera() {
        if let camera = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "camera", recursively: true) {
            cameraNode = camera
            cameraNode.name = "camera"
        }
    }

    func setupPlayer() {
        if let player = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "player", recursively: true) {
            playerNode = player
            playerNode.name = "player"
        }
    }

    func setupSegments() {
        if let segment = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "segment", recursively: true) {
            floorSegments.append(segment)
        }
    }




}

extension GameViewController: SCNSceneRendererDelegate {


    func updateSegments() {

        playerNode.position = playerNode.presentation.position
        if let lastSegmentClone = floorSegments.last?.clone() {

            lastSegmentClone.childNodes.forEach { (node) in
                node.removeFromParentNode()
            }


            if abs(playerNode.position.z - lastSegmentClone.position.z) < 30 {
                // set up next segment
                lastSegmentClone.position = SCNVector3(lastSegmentClone.position.x, lastSegmentClone.position.y + 4, lastSegmentClone.position.z - 4)
                floorSegments.append(lastSegmentClone)


                // Add falling blocks to the segment
                for _ in 0...2 {

                    let boxClone = box.clone()
                    let randomX = Int.random(in: -2...2)
                    let randomY = Int.random(in: 1...3)
                    boxClone.eulerAngles.z = Float(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-45))
                    boxClone.position = SCNVector3(randomX, randomY, -randomY)
                    lastSegmentClone.addChildNode(boxClone)

                }

                // Add falling blocks to the segment
                for (index,segment) in floorSegments.enumerated().reversed() {
                    if segment.position.z > playerNode.position.z + 5 {
                        floorSegments.remove(at: index)
                        segment.childNodes.forEach { (node) in
                            node.removeFromParentNode()
                        }
                        segment.removeFromParentNode()
                    }
                }

                scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lastSegmentClone)
            }
        }
    }

    func updatePositions() {

        if let playerPhysicsBod = playerNode.physicsBody {
            playerPhysicsBod.velocity.x = (lastXPosition - playerNode.position.x) * 8
            playerPhysicsBod.velocity.z = -5
            print("player velocity is \(playerNode.physicsBody!.velocity)")
        }
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        updatePositions()
        updateSegments()
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't remove and add more clone(), which is slow. Just hide those and then unhide at right positions.

Comment: Also playerPhysicsBod.allowsResting = false may help.

Comment: @E.Coms Thank you for your help, unfortunately I have already tested with allowsResting turned off, and without any adding any clones at all. Very strange stuff

Comment: One possibility is the location was far from origin. In your scene, you may simulate the other way and make active scene happening around origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to judge w/o seeing scn files.

I hope there is no collision between the player and floor nodes...

Player's Position is a float, It might be inexact comparison for equality. I think you should avoid player's position adjustment, as it should be almost the same:

```
playerNode.position = playerNode.presentation.position
```

Why don't you keep reference on an empty segment node?

In the method `setupSegments` clone the segment and after removing children nodes, keep it. No point to always remove children nodes:

```
 lastSegmentClone.childNodes.forEach { (node) in
            node.removeFromParentNode()
        }
```

Plus I think you should "reverse" the order in updateSegments:

```
if let lastSegment = floorSegments.last { // no cloning here....

            if abs(playerNode.position.z - lastSegment.position.z) < 30 {

               let lastSegmentClone = lastSegment.clone() // better to use emptySegmentNode

                 /* If empty segment then it's not needed to remove children nodes...
                  lastSegmentClone.childNodes.forEach { (node) in
                   node.removeFromParentNode() */
```

Also if you're removing parent node, children nodes are going to be removed automatically....

```
// Avoid commented code
/*segment.childNodes.forEach { (node) in
                            node.removeFromParentNode()
                        }*/
                        segment.removeFromParentNode()
```

No sure, but perhaps for floor segments it is better to use custom action for removal:

```
// calculate somehow wait duration, based on the player's position, velocity or use pure constant..
   let removeAction = SCNAction.sequence([SCNAction.waitForDuration(2.0), SCNAction.removeFromParent()])

   lastSegmentClone.run(removeAction)
```

In such case you just need a reference on the last floor node, and empty floor node.

Comment: Turns out that the first part of your answer was the root of the problem. playerNode.position = playerNode.presentation.position